# what is the core technology of Google advertising pushing?

Tags: adsense, google-ads-api

By Google adsense/adwords, after pasting some code scripts in one website, then google will push the ads. to the website automatically.

How google do this? What is the core technology of pushing ads. to the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core tech is HTTP!

When a user visits your site, the user's browser loads your page.  As it loads your page the browser also loads the Google ad script. When this ad script loads it makes a HTTP request off to Google servers.  When they Google gets the request they provide a suitable ad back to the user.  Google have a bunch of technology internally that decides *which* ad to show to your user, but that doesn't affect how the ad gets to your site.

This all happens in a very short time - fractions of a second - so it looks seamless to our eyes.